# AWS S3 folder permission for users

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

My scenario is as follows:

1. Every user on my web application has uuid as primary key.
2. My web application users can upload images to their own folder(folder name is their uuid,
   ex:
   clients/0d75db15-07ad-4800-a5de-1fe82a7bf52e/
   clients/0faf6315-6ba9-478d-aaa5-3cd2bd3b3b6e/
3. Every user can only access their own folder and files under the folder.

I know that IAM policies has permissions but not folder level or object level.
Is there any solutions for the scenario?
Thanks for any suggestions and answers!

Comment: You **can** set permissions based on prefixes in S3, what makes you think that's no possible?

Comment: as @Maurice already pointed it works. [Writing IAM Policies: Grant Access to User-Specific Folders in an Amazon S3 Bucket](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/writing-iam-policies-grant-access-to-user-specific-folders-in-an-amazon-s3-bucket/)

Comment: Thanks for answering. The following condition is a part of example in [Writing IAM Policies...](https://aws.amazon.com/tw/blogs/security/writing-iam-policies-grant-access-to-user-specific-folders-in-an-amazon-s3-bucket/).

"Condition":{"StringEquals":{"s3:prefix":["","home/", "home/David"],"s3:delimiter":["/"]}}.

However, If my web application has 1000+ user and folders, should I add 1000+ prefix string into that "s3:prefix" array?
Or did I get it wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that your application has 1000+ users, you should not be relying on IAM policies or S3 Bucket policies to manage the security.

Instead, all objects should be kept as **private** and the application should generate [Amazon S3 pre-signed URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html), which grant time-limited access to private objects stored in Amazon S3.

It would work like this:

- A user logs-in to your application
- When user requests access to an image, or if application wants to send them an HTML page that includes images using `<img src='xxx'>` tags, the application should:

  - Verify that the user is entitled to access the object
  - If so, **generate a pre-signed URL** that grants temporary access to the object
- The user's browser then accesses the provided URL
- Amazon S3 will verify that the pre-signed URL is valid and then provides access to the object